# How to scale points within a bounding box to match another bounding box?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

It's for a handwriting recognition algorithm I'm working on. I'm trying to scale the set of points so that no matter how small or big you write the digit, it all gets scaled to the same size in the end.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. My approach was this. I want the bounding box to be scaled within to match within the bounding bo defined by x = (-256,256) and y = (-256,256) perfectly. It should stretch and squish all points so that the 4 corners match that size. So what I did was calculate the max x distance between the points, then divide that into 512 which should give me how much I need to scale each point on the x-axis to match the -256, 256 borders. Repeat that for the y-axis. Intuitively I thought it should work but it doesn't.

How do I do this? And what is this called in Mathematics what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Here's my Python code and my attempt at it. pointsmod should have the scaled points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

points = [(73, 172), (3, 171), (-82, 170), (-130, 164), (-130, 103), (-130, 51), (-89, 80), (-35, 91), (16, 81), (57, 55), (71, 9), (65, -39), (36, -77), (-18, -85), (-65, -68), (-104, -32)]

def boundingbox(points):
    x_min = min(point[0] for point in points)
    x_max = max(point[0] for point in points)
    y_min = min(point[1] for point in points)
    y_max = max(point[1] for point in points)
    return [(x_min, y_min), (x_min, y_max), (x_max, y_max), (x_max, y_min)]

bb = boundingbox(points)

def distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt((point1[0] - point2[0])**2+(point1[1] - point2[1])**2)

xlen = distance(bb[0], bb[3])
ylen = distance(bb[0],bb[1])

pointsmod = []
xfac = 512/xlen
yfac = 512/ylen

for point in points: # My  attempt at scaling the points
    x = point[0]*xfac
    y = point[1]*yfac
    pointsmod.append((x,y))

plt.xlim(-256, 256)
plt.ylim(-256, 256)

plt.scatter(*zip(*points))
plt.scatter(*zip(*pointsmod))

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're not taking the different origins into account.  Your bounding box is not centered on (0,0).  Say we have

```
xmin = min(point[0] for point in points)
xmax = max(point[0] for point in points)
ymin = min(point[1] for point in points)
ymax = max(point[1] for point in points)
xlen = xmax - xmin
ylen = ymax - ymin
```

Then the translation from the `points` box to (-256,+256) is this:

```
def scale( oldx, oldy ):
    newx = (oldx - xmin) * 512 / xlen - 256
    newy = (oldy - ymin) * 512 / ylen - 256
    return newx, newy
```

That moves the (0,0) to upper left, then does the scaling, then moves the origin back to the middle.